# create an array of objects based on another array of objects programmatically

Tags: javascript

here is the array of objects I have:

```
var sentences = [
{ id: "1-1", layer: ["A"] },
{ id: "1-2", layer: ["B"] },
{ id: "1-3", layer: ["C"] },
{ id: "2-1", layer: ["D"] },
{ id: "2-2", layer: ["E"] },
{ id: "2-3", layer: ["F"] },
{ id: "3-1", layer: ["G"] },
{ id: "3-2", layer: ["H"] },
{ id: "3-3", layer: ["I"] },
];
```

the first number in id is the slide number and the second one is for the sentence on that slide. for example `id: 3-2` is slide 3 and sentence 2.

so we have 3 slides here...

Now the problem is How can I programmatically fill the slides array like this:

```
var slides = [
{ slide_id: "1", slide_layer: ["A", "B", "C"] },
{ slide_id: "2", slide_layer: ["D", "E", "F"] },
{ slide_id: "3", slide_layer: ["G", "H", "I"] },
]
```

I'm still researching but I can't find a proper way...

Comment: Please add the code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to group slides by id using object as accumulator, and then you can get array of values from that object with `Object.values` method.

```js
var sentences = [{"id":"1-1","layer":["A"]},{"id":"1-2","layer":["B"]},{"id":"1-3","layer":["C"]},{"id":"2-1","layer":["D"]},{"id":"2-2","layer":["E"]},{"id":"2-3","layer":["F"]},{"id":"3-1","layer":["G"]},{"id":"3-2","layer":["H"]},{"id":"3-3","layer":["I"]}]

const result = Object.values(sentences.reduce((r, {id, layer}) => {
  let [a, b] = id.split('-');
  if(!r[a]) r[a] = { slide_id: a, slide_layer: [] }
  r[a].slide_layer[b - 1] = layer[0]
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution with easy to read code.

```
let slides = [];
for(let data of sentences) {
    let slideId = parseInt(data.id.split("-")[0]);
    let slideIndex = slideId-1;
    if (!slides[slideIndex]) slides[slideIndex] = {"slide_id": slideId, "slide_layer": []}
    slides[slideIndex].slide_layer.push(data.layer[0]);
}
console.log("slides", slides);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `Array.prototype.reduce` to accumulate the slides from the `sentences` array. We need to test if the slide object is already there or not in the accumulator array using `Array.prototype.findIndex()` and `slide_id`.

If it is present (`idx` is `>= 0`) we need to add the `layer` to the `slide_layer` array property of the slide object.

```js
var sentences = [
{ id: "1-1", layer: ["A"] },
{ id: "1-2", layer: ["B"] },
{ id: "1-3", layer: ["C"] },
{ id: "2-1", layer: ["D"] },
{ id: "2-2", layer: ["E"] },
{ id: "2-3", layer: ["F"] },
{ id: "3-1", layer: ["G"] },
{ id: "3-2", layer: ["H"] },
{ id: "3-3", layer: ["I"] },
];
var slides = sentences.reduce((acc, ele) => {
 let idx = acc.findIndex(obj => obj.slide_id === ele.id.split("-")[0]);
 if(idx >= 0){
   let obj = acc[idx];
   obj.slide_layer.push(ele.layer[0]);
 }else{
  acc.push({slide_id: ele.id.split("-")[0], slide_layer : [ele.layer[0]]});
 }
 return acc;
}, []);
console.log(slides);
```

Answer (score 1):

The array reduce() method in JavaScript is used to reduce the array to a single value and executes a provided function for each value of the array (from left-to-right) and the return value of the function is stored in an accumulator.

```
const output = Object.values(sentences.reduce((k, {id, layer}) => {
  let [frst, sec] = id.split('-');
  if(!k[frst]) 
  k[frst] = { slide_id: frst, slide_layer: [] }
  k[frst].slide_layer[sec - 1] = layer[0]
  return k;
}, {}))
```